# operand types are incompatible "BSTR" and "const char*"

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wmi-query, operands

Hello im using visual studio c++ 2010 and im still not that good at it .I'm using wmi query and i want to use if statement before i cout the result here is the code

```
IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
    bstr_t("WQL"), 
    bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem"),
    WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, 
    NULL,
    &pEnumerator);

if (FAILED(hres))
{
    cout << "Query for CS failed."
        << " Error code = 0x" 
        << hex << hres << endl;
    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;               // Program has failed.
}


// Get the data from the query 

IWbemClassObject *pclsObj;
ULONG uReturn = 0;

while (pEnumerator)
{
    HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, 
        &pclsObj, &uReturn);

    if(0 == uReturn)
    {
        break;
    }

    VARIANT vtProp;


    // Get the value of the Name property
    hr = pclsObj->Get(L"Manufacturer", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);


    if (vtProp.bstrVal == "test")  //// HERE IS THE PROB HOW TO FIX HERE?I WANT TO SAY IF THE RESULT ="WHATEVER" THEN 

    wcout << "\Manufacturer : " << vtProp.bstrVal << endl; // or do stuff 

    VariantClear(&vtProp);

    pclsObj->Release();
```

the error is : error C2446: '==' : no conversion from 'const char *' to 'BSTR'
I'm still a beginner and i dont know hwo to solve this , please help !!!

Comment: why not use wide strings, e.g. write `_bstr_t( L"WQL" )`. they use `wchar_t` instead of `char`.

Comment: There are a number of great articles on codeproject.com on BSTR, _bstr_t, CComBSTR, char*, wchar_t*, std::string etc. They are worth a read if you'll be using BSTR a fair bit. There are a few gotchas that you should not forget.

Comment: It might have been helpful to mention that your code snippet has been copied from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390423(v=vs.85).aspx Am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

THere are at least two issues here:

- BSTR looks like a string but is not exactly as a C string.  Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  So you have to be careful about the difference.
- even if vtProp.bstrVal would be a C strings, your comparison wouldn't work, because `vtProp.bstrVal == "test"` would compare the adress of the pointers and not the content of the strings.

For a simple comparison, like in your code, the solution would be to replace your test with

```
wcscmp(vtProp.bstrVal, L"test")==0
```

Comment: THANK YOU ! Yes you're totally right ! thanks again !! another thing Any ideas if i want to say for example "if the result contains the word "test" for example and not only "test" as a whole result then // do stuff"

Comment: You can try `wcsstr(vtProp.bstrVal, L"test")!=0`:  the result of wcsstr() is not null when the second string is contained within the first one.